# Catch failure of FetchContent_Declare

Tags: cmake, gitlab

Please advise how to catch a failure in the `FetchContent_Declare` command. Something like:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        Eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/cantonios/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4.0
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE)
if (what)
    # Try find_package or a different URL
endif()
```

The current scenario (albeit extremely rare) is that the git server is unreachable, and has broken all of our builds:

https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2336